# Primefaces socket can't receive message from Primefaces push

Tags: sockets, jsf-2, primefaces

In a JSF facelet, I define a p:socket component to receive the message returned from PushEndPoint.

When the JSF facelet is displayed in a web browser, the p:socket component can receive the pushed message.

However, when the JSF facelet is not displayed, the p:socket component just misses the push message, which is normal because p:socket is not rendered.

I am wondering if there is a way to make the pushed message 'waiting' somewhere, when next time the JSF facelet is displayed, p:socket can receive the 'waiting' message.

Many thanks.

Cheers.